# how to customize tooltip in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Am using Bootstrap '4.0.0-alpha.6' and Im trying to update tooltip styles to customize it. Right now, Im using Bootstrap 4 and also, I added some custom css class also. But it is not responding as per my custom style while mouse hover.

HTML

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Testing tooltip with custom style" class="red-tooltip" (click)="nodeion(node)">
    some text
</span>
```

CSS

```
.red-tooltip + .tooltip-top > .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: #f00;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

but, after this update, it is reflected as per the change, it is stil showing default style of bootstrap.
Any help, please?

Comment: Did you try deleting `+ .tooltip-top > .tooltip-inner` ?

Comment: now, i tried, but it still not working

Comment: What is the expected result? I tried it and it gives a background-color to the`.red-tooltip` span

Comment: am getting the default style, instead, i need a customized one, i mean background color and padding etc need to be changed as per my values

Comment: could you please give me fiddle link that is working

Comment: Is this the expected result? https://jsfiddle.net/jfmh88yh/1/

Comment: nope, the text 'Testing tooltip with..' should come as per the color specfied, i mean as per the style mentioned

Answer (score 3):

```js
// Initialize tooltip component
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})

// Initialize popover component
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

```css
.tooltip-inner{max-width:200px;padding:3px 8px;color:#fff;text-align:center;background-color:#f2f2f2 !important;border-radius:.25rem}
```

```html
<title>My Example</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
body {
padding-top: 1em;
} 
</style> <div class="container-fluid">
  
<p style="margin:40px;">Check out my <a target="_blank" href="https://www.quackit.com/css/grid/tutorial/" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Build advanced layouts easily with CSS!">Grid tutorial</a>, as you never know when you might need it!</p>

</div>
 <span data-toggle="tooltip"  class="red-tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Testing tooltip with custom style" class="red-tooltip" (click)="nodeion(node)">some text</span>
 
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Popper -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: am trying this inside a angular 2 compoent scss file, not in jquery

Comment: ok please  try to edit https://github.com/bharatraj88/angular2-tooltip   anguler tooltip plugin scss

Answer (score 1):

You need the [general sibling `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) selector here, since the generated tooltip element isn't a direct sibling `+` of your `.red-tooltip`:

```
.red-tooltip ~ .tooltip > .tooltip-inner
```

In SCSS it would be:

```
.red-tooltip {
  &~.tooltip {
    &>.tooltip-inner {
      /* your custom styles */
    }
  }
}
```

See this working example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 5em;
}

.red-tooltip ~ .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #f00;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Testing tooltip with custom style" class="red-tooltip" (click)="nodeion(node)">some text</span>
```

Comment: am trying this inside a angular 2 component, not in a jquery

Comment: It's just CSS, doesn't matter where you use it. I used jQuery here to show a working example. Have you tried `.red-tooltip ~ .tooltip > .tooltip-inner` as selector?

Comment: i tried the same in .scss file not in css file, but, it is not working as expected

Comment: I'm afraid we need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to really help you finding whats causing this issue...